# PHP: static variable outside of class

Tags: php, static

I have seen in 3rd party code a variable declared as static, but outside of any class, simply in a "normal" function.

```
<?php
function doStuff(){
    static $something = null;
}
?>
```

I have never seen `static` used this way, and I cannot find anything it in the PHP documentation.

Is this legal PHP code? Is this effectively the same as a global variable? If not, what is the purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static):

> Another important feature of variable scoping is the static variable.
>   A static variable exists only in a local function scope, but it does
>   not lose its value when program execution leaves this scope.
>
> ```
> <?php
> function test()
> {
>      static $a = 0;
>      echo $a;
>      $a++;
> }
> ?>
> ```
>
> Now, $a is initialized only in first call of function and every time
>   the test() function is called it will print the value of $a and
>   increment it.

Comment: @Fraser Nope. It's initialised only once.

Comment: @Fraser I have quoted my whole answer from the PHP manual. If you disagree with it, please contact them :).

Comment: I would kindly ask the downvoter to state his reasons - I would be happy to improve my answer.